# The named parameter 'shape' isn't defined. The named parameter 'borderRadius' isn't defined.The named parameter 'activeColor' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: PinCodeTextField(
                length: 6,
                obscureText: false,
                autoFocus: true,
                keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
                animationType: AnimationType.fade,
               shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                fieldHeight: 50,
                fieldWidth: 40,
                cursorWidth: 1.5,
                activeColor : UIColors.primaryColor,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey[500],
                selectedColor: Colors.black,
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "JFFlat"),
                onChanged: (value) {},
                onCompleted: (val) {
                  bloc.setCode(val);
                },
              ),
          ),
```

Comment: Is `PinCodeTextField` from a package or have you create that widget in your project? You will need to update your question to provide more details.

Comment: ok, Rohan Thacker

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything in the `boxDecoration` parameter

Answer (score 0):

PinCodeTextField is updated but you are using the code for the old version
You have wrap those properties inside a PinTheme

```
PinCodeTextField(
                length: 6,
                obscureText: false,
                autoFocus: true,
                keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
                animationType: AnimationType.fade,
                pinTheme: PinTheme(
                shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                fieldHeight: 50,
                fieldWidth: 40,
                activeColor : UIColors.primaryColor,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey[500],
                selectedColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                cursorWidth: 1.5,
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "JFFlat"),
                onChanged: (value) {},
                onCompleted: (val) {
                  bloc.setCode(val);
                },
              ),
```

Comment: thnx Sajad Abdollahi